# Auto-arrange items in a table depending on the size of the screen

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a table with square clickable boxes in them. I need to make sure that these boxes appear correctly on any sized device. This means that I need to find a way to automatically put the table content into rows so that all of the square boxes fit. Eg if you where on desktop the arrangement would be 4x4, if you where on a mobile it would be different to ensure that all of the links can be shown. It doesn't matter the arrangement of these boxes, just that they are all shown.

My HTML

```html
<h2>My Tools</h2>

<table class="my-tools">
<tr>
    <td><a href="http://x.com" target="_blank"><div style="background-color: #11237C"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/561/561127.svg"><p>Webmail</p></div></a></td>
    <td><a href="http://x.com" target="_blank"><div style="background-color: #971d33"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/126/126496.svg"><p>Portal</p></div></a></td>
    <td><a href="http://x.com" target="_blank"><div style="background-color: #867750"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1556/1556324.svg"><p>My HR</p></div></a></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

And CSS

```css
.my-tools div {
    padding: 30px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
}

.my-tools img {
    filter: invert(100%) sepia(43%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(30deg) brightness(113%) contrast(101%);
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px
}

.my-tools p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: large;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px
}

.my-tools div:hover {
    filter: brightness(85%) 
}

.my-tools a:hover {
    text-decoration:none!important
}
```

Comment: You would need to take them *out* of a table layout to do that; tables aren't designed for responsiveness. You can use `display` to adjust on the fly, though you may benefit from flexbox, where you can use the `order` property.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Checkout Bootstrap 4 responsive tables, towards the bottom of this page >>> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/ _ This is a tutorial about them >>> https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-tables.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        } 
        h2 {
            text-align: center;
        } 
        .my-tools {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .my-tools tr {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
        }
        .my-tools td {
            border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
        }   
        .my-tools td:last-child {
            border-right: 0px;
        }     
        .my-tools div {
            padding: 30px;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 15px;
        }        
        .my-tools img {
            filter: invert(100%) sepia(43%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(30deg) brightness(113%) contrast(101%);
            width: 85px;
            height: 85px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 20px
        }        
        .my-tools p {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: large;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 20px
        }        
        .my-tools div:hover {
            filter: brightness(85%)
        }        
        .my-tools a:hover {
            text-decoration: none!important
        }
```

```html
<h2>My Tools</h2>
    <table class="my-tools">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://x.com" target="_blank">
                    <div style="background-color: #11237C"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/561/561127.svg">
                        <p>Webmail</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="http://x.com" target="_blank">
                    <div style="background-color: #971d33"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/126/126496.svg">
                        <p>Portal</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="http://x.com" target="_blank">
                    <div style="background-color: #867750"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1556/1556324.svg">
                        <p>My HR</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```